# MySQL join for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have 2 tables. Table kind and table living.

In the table kind, it has id, kind_o & living_id while in living it has id & type.
Example data.

```
KIND

id          kind_o         living_id
1           dog            1
2           narra          2

LIVING

id          type
1           animal
2           tree
```

How can I query in CodeIgniter if I want to return ex. `SELECT * kind WHERE id = 1` and i want to return also all the data inside living table?

Example output:

```
id   kind_o   living_id    living.id    type
1    dog      1            1            animal
                           2            tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
    $this->db->select('k.*,l.type');
    $this->db->from('kind as k');
    $this->db->join('living as l','l.id = k.living_id');
    $this->db->where('l.id','1');//use Kind id Here you want to use.
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $this->db->last_query();
    return $query->result_array();
```

See [Document](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: why do i use `l.id` here? when I use to `WHERE` is the kind's id?

Comment: because you have to tell the mysql that what is the common field between both tables and it is `l.id`, I'm not retrieving it in result.

Answer (score 0):

select k.id as kind_id, k.kind_o, k.living_id, l.id as living_id, l.type FROM kind k join living l on (k.living_id=l.id);

Always prefer to select fields comma seperated then using select *. 
select * usually takes time compared to query selecting all required feilds.